# How to fetch the data from Event

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, entry, events

I am trying to fetch the content from an event `onEntrySave` but I don't know how to access the entry's properties from the event. So far I have got the event handler working I would just like to fetch the data, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#listening-for-events

The [entry](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel) will be in the `params` property of the `$event`.  You can access it like so:

```
$event->params['entry']
```